# PHP: Function name must be a string?

Tags: php

I am trying to use a function that I made to convert numbers into some words but the function give me an error whenever I am trying to use it in iteration.

```
$status = array('freie&nbsp;Plätze','ausgebucht','nicht mehr buchbar','Restplätze','auf Anfrage','entfällt');
```

**I have numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) which I am using function $status to convert**

it **working properly in this form** -

```
$status[$zeile->status];
```

but when I tried to use in **while loop iteration it gives an error** -

```
$status($zeile->($i)status);
```

How will I modify this function to use it in the While loop or any iteration?

Comment: Hey there. **You can't treat an array as a function**.

Comment: @Jwan I asked for another method no one helps, they only focused on downvote

Comment: If you can be more clear. I might be able to help you. Just post the hole code and I can help :).

Comment: *to convert numbers into some words* You're just looking for something like str_replace/preg_replace

Comment: @KevinGales I think he means to list all the array elements in forloop. but not really sure what he means.

Comment: That would just be foreach( ) then...

Comment: @KevinGales I have number (1,2,3,4,5,6) which i am trying to convert with help of status function

Comment: Are the numbers in array?

Comment: Yes the numbers are in array

Comment: Then use str_replace $numbers array with $status array

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue after trying some methods and suggested by @kevingales in the comment by `str_replace()` it saved my day, Thank you all.

```
<?php

$phrase  =  ($zeile->($i)status);
$healthy = [0,1,2,3,4,5 ];
$yummy   = ['freie&nbsp;Plätze','ausgebucht','nicht mehr buchbar','Restplätze','auf Anfrage','entfällt'];

$newPhrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);

echo $newPhrase;

?>
```

Comment: What you are showing and asking here is incomplete, faulty and not reproducible.

Comment: could you please elaborate @jspit have you check the question? I also asked for how will I modify to get the desire results